# compiling returns error using ANt

Tags: ant, build, webdriver

When I try to build my Selenium tests, getting BUILD failed message with the below errors. [I might be missing something in my build.xml] , could someone please have a look and let me know what am missing here plz.

I checked my build.xml, but didnt find a clue.

Errors:

```
7: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
    [javac] import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    [javac]                                   ^
....
.............
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\xxx\build.xml:70: Compile failed; see the compiler err
or output for details.
```

Here is my build.xml

```
<project name="myproj" default="usage" basedir=".">
    <property name="ws.home" value="${basedir}" />
    <!--<property name="ws.jars" value="${basedir}/lib" /> -->
    <property name="ws.jars" value="C:\Jars" />
    <property name="test.dest" value="${ws.home}/build" />
    <property name="test.src" value="${ws.home}/src" />
    <property name="ng.result" value="test-output" />

    <target name="setClassPath" unless="test.classpath">
        <path id="classpath_jars">
            <fileset dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar" />
        </path>

        <pathconvert pathsep=":"
                     property="test.classpath" 
                     refid="classpath_jars"/>
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="setClassPath">
        <tstamp>
            <format property="start.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" />
        </tstamp>

        <condition property="ANT" 
                   value="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant.bat"
                   else="${env.ANT_HOME}/bin/ant">
            <os family="windows" />
        </condition>

        <taskdef name="testng" classpath="${test.classpath}"
                 classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" />
    </target>

    <!-- all -->
    <target name="all">
    </target>

    <!-- clean -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${test.dest}"/>
    </target>

    <!-- compile -->

    <target name="compile" depends="init, clean">
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir="${test.dest}" includes="**/*" />
        </delete>
    </target>

    <echo message="Making directory...."/>
    <mkdir dir="${test.dest}"/>
    <echo message="classpath:... ${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="${test.classpath}"/>
    <echo message="compiling...."/>

    <javac
        includeantruntime="false"
        debug="true"
        destdir="${test.dest}"
        srcdir="${test.src}"
        target="1.6" 
        classpath="${test.classpath}">
    </javac>

    <!-- build -->
    <target name="build" depends="init">
    </target>

    <!-- run -->
    <target name="run" depends="compile">
        <testng classpath="${test.classpath}:${test.dest}" suitename="Default suite">
            <xmlfileset dir="${ws.home}" includes="testng.xml" />
        </testng>
    </target>

    <!-- Usage -->
    <target name="usage">
        <echo>ant run will execute the test</echo>
    </target>

    <path id="test.c">
        <filelist dir="${ws.jars}" includes="*.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="makexsltreports">
        <mkdir dir="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>

        <xslt in="${ng.result}/testng-results.xml"
              style="${ws.home}/testng-results.xsl"
              out="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output/index.html" >
            <param name="testNgXslt.outputDir"
                   expression="${ws.home}/XSLT_Reports/output"/>
            <param name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals" expression="true" />
        </xslt>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm confused. You have a `javac` task outside any of the `target`? Can you try to repost your build file?

Comment: Thanks coolcfan  for your reply. Actually my problem is solved when I use pathelement in my build.xml and few other changes.

Comment: then again plz repost your build file and post your solution as an answer and accept it.